# Wrapper Not Expanding With Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am in the process of creating a slide in/out side bar for my page but I cannot do so unless my wrapper DIV covers the whole length of the body's width and height, which it doesn't and I don't know why.

I'm not entirely sure what code to include so I've included some here which I think is. If you need to preview all the code, I have provided a Pastebin link below.

Image of Issue - [http://i.imgur.com/wWNAeBP.png](https://i.imgur.com/wWNAeBP.png)
[image]
See All Code Here If Needs Be:

HTML - http://pastebin.com/TQT6Xc4z
CSS - http://pastebin.com/mS5Gh56x

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <h3 id="welcometext">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" Book Search" class="searchstyle"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #333">
                    <a href="1Index.html" class="link">
                        <span style="color: #ed786a">Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="2Catgeories.html" class="link">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Find Us
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { /* ### */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Arial, "Open Sans", sans-serif-light, sans-serif, "Segoe UI";
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Have really been stuck on this for a good while now while trying to create the opening and closing sidebar so will appreciate any help at all!

Comment: @Careen Not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: @Careen It's already there.

Comment: @Careen html,body{ margin:0; padding: 0; height:100%; width:100%}

Comment: It is because you have a position:fixed element inside your wrapper, which will affect the height.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your wrapper css to

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through your containers and remove :

```
height: 100%; // this is scaling your containers to the window height leaving white space...

   #containerthree {
   width: 80%;
   height: 100%;   <-- here is the problem
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: center;
   color: #888888;
   padding: 0 0 2em 0;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
   box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
  }
```